# Remove lines from Python and Kivy file

Tags: python, kivy-language

Python:

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty 
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class TracePhonicsWindow(Screen): 
    alphabets = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)] 
    current_alphabet_index = 0 
    line = ObjectProperty(None)

def get_current_alphabet(self):
    return self.alphabets[self.current_alphabet_index]

def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    super().on_touch_down(touch)
    with self.canvas:
        Color(1, 1, 0)
        touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))
        self.line = touch.ud['line']

def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    super().on_touch_move(touch)
    touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
    if self.validate_trace(touch):
        self.proceed_to_next_alphabet()

def validate_trace(self, touch):
    if 0.3 < touch.x < 0.7 and 0.3 < touch.y < 0.7:
        return True
    return False

def proceed_to_next_alphabet(self):
    self.current_alphabet_index += 1
    if self.current_alphabet_index >= len(self.alphabets):
        self.current_alphabet_index = 0
    self.ids.alphabet_label.text = self.get_current_alphabet()

def next_alphabet(self):
    self.clear_tracing()
    self.proceed_to_next_alphabet()

def clear_tracing(self):
    if self.line is not None:
        self.canvas.remove(self.line)
        self.line = ObjectProperty(None)
```

Kivy:

```
<TracePhonicsWindow>:
    name: "tracephonics"
    alphabet_label: alphabet_label
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: alphabet_label
            text: root.get_current_alphabet()
            font_size: '100sp'
        Button:
            text: 'Next'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .95 , 'center_y': .05}
            size: 75,50
            size_hint: None,None
            on_release: root.next_alphabet()
```

This is a simple code for a tracing alphabet game. What I need is when user click on the "Next" button, the lines drawn by the user should be removed as well as the following alphabet should be displayed. Same thing should go when user click on the "Clear" button as well (Clear button shall be updated later). The problem I am facing now is that when user click on the "Next" button, the lines drawn are not removed but the following alphabet appears. After multiple attempts, I am still unable to clear the lines.
Please do help me with this problem.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.